# Error with compiling Python code that includes Rust written modules

Tags: python, rust, compiler-errors, auto-py-to-exe, maturin

So I have written an app that uses a bit of Rust code, and while using "auto-py-to-exe" to turn it into an executable, it gives this error when I run it:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_clean'

(data_clean is my rust module)

I used maturin for converting rust -> python and I ran 'maturin develop' on it successfully, it works as expected within my IDE.

I included the folder with all of my Rust code in it, I'm not sure why it's giving me a tough time.

Comment: `maturin develop` installs the built library into the currently-activated virtual environment, are you running auto-py-to-exe / the generated pyinstaller command in the same virtual environment? Your IDE may have created a virtual environment for you.

Comment: Yeah I looked into that, running maturin develop and running the GUI from the same venv produced the same error